# Can't use rails params even though I can see them. Specifically charge_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, shopify-app

I've been working on hooking up my Rails, Shopify embedded app to the Shopify billing API. It seems simple enough:

1. You create a new Shopify RecurringApplicationCharge object through the API, submit it to Shopify.
2. They return the object with additional fields filled in, including a 'confirmation_url' which you can redirect to.
3. This confirmation URL has a charge_id param, which you can use to activate the billing.

I can get through the above fine and can even see the 'charge_id' param in the log as well as when I run params.inspect . However, I can't use it. Every time I try and assign params to an instance variable I get 'nil class'.

**Controller**

```
class HomeController < AuthenticatedController
  before_action :require_login, except: [:activate_charge]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: [:activate_charge]
  before_action :require_subscription, except: [:activate_charge]


    def require_subscription
      unless ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.current
          @recurring_application_charge = ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.new
          @recurring_application_charge.name = "Monthly Plan"
          @recurring_application_charge.price =  15.0
          @recurring_application_charge.return_url = "https://xxxxx.ngrok.io/activatecharge"
          @recurring_application_charge.test = true
          @recurring_application_charge.trial_days = 7
          @recurring_application_charge.save

          if @recurring_application_charge.id
            #@tokens[:confirmation_url] = @recurring_application_charge.confirmation_url
            fullpage_redirect_to(@recurring_application_charge.T)
          end
        end
    end

    def activate_charge
      @params = params[:charge_id]

      #@recurring_application_charge = ShopifyAPI::RecurringApplicationCharge.find(params[:charge_id])
      #@recurring_application_charge.status == "accepted" ? @recurring_application_charge.activate : redirect_to('/')
      #@recurring_application_charge.save

      redirect_to('/')
    end

    def recurring_application_charge_params
        params.require(:recurring_application_charge).permit(:name, :price, :capped_amount, :terms, :trial_days, :charge_id)
    end
```

**params.inspect**

```
<ActionController::Parameters {"charge_id"=>"12271520309", "hmac"=>"f7a75bba157ef40b3144d8d0e8ceb8b37628ea294fbe16887b623c0d311d84da", "locale"=>"en-GB", "session"=>"f8b8ef448a1d9883e4884c858e0bc39d789d53d2eeffffb34c42f5bc390af6f1", "shop"=>"xxxxx.myshopify.com", "timestamp"=>"1578555752", "controller"=>"home", "action"=>"activate_charge"} permitted: true>
```

**Some clues**

- I have an API controller which I use for other things, this is not authenticated by Shopify or Clearance. I can get 'charge_id' param if I use this controller (although this controller cant be use for other reasons).
- I've played around with trying to make sure strong params allow for it, but I'm not writing to a model, so this shouldn't matter?
- On an older Shopify page on how to set billing up, they have this line of code in the first object creation phase, that I haven't been able to implement:

```
    @tokens[:confirmation_url] = recurring_application_charge.confirmation_url
```

Any help would be great, I can't figure out if this is a really simple problem or whether there's an authentication issue I'm completely oblivious to.

Thanks!

**Edit**
The Return, when params.class and params.inspect is called

```
ActionController::Parameters

<ActionController::Parameters {"charge_id"=>"12284756045", "hmac"=>"9ff4d8a30d623f2d03d0226ff3d98c780e451615d630c149697e5b2dd4ffd4b5", "locale"=>"en-GB", "session"=>"f8b8ef448a1d9883e4884c852e0bc39d789d53d2eeffffb34c42f5bc390af6f1", "shop"=>"xxxx.myshopify.com", "timestamp"=>"1578737591", "controller"=>"home", "action"=>"activate_charge"} permitted: false>
```

Another piece of info, if I add the following to the controller:

```
params = params.to_h[:charge_id]
```

Then call params["charge_id"], from the view I can get the charge_id returned.
However, when I try and assign it to @charge_id in the controller, then try and call @charge_id in the view to test it, it returns nothing :S

```
params = params.to_h[:charge_id]
@charge_id = params["charge_id"]
```

Comment: You said every time you assign params to an instance variable, you get nil class; I presumed you were talking about `@params = params[:charge_id]`? If so, then you were saying `@params` at that point equals `nil`? If so, can you add `puts params.class` and `puts params.inspect` just below `@params = params[:charge_id]`, and let me know the output. I have a feeling maybe somewhere, `params` object has been modified or something why you instead got a `nil` value.

Comment: Totally agree with @Jay-ArPolidario, check class of your ID and the class of what you want it to be assigned to.

Comment: Hey Jay and ARK, thanks for the help. I've just added the output to the bottom of my question.

Comment: I've now figured out that for some odd reason when Shopify redirects to /activate_charge, my app is ignoring all of my code in the controller's active_charge method. I think that's where my problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

The `ActionController::Parameters` use `"charge_id"`, not `:charge_id`. Maybe you should try that. Or work with `params.to_h[:charge_id]`, as `to_h` will return a HashWithIndifferentAccess.

Comment: Hi Salz, thanks for the help. Just tried '@params = params["charge_id"]' in the controller, then '<%= @params %>' in the view. Nothing returned I'm afraid

Comment: I think you might be onto something with the 'params.to_h[:charge_id]', however, rails still isn't letting me assign the result to an instance variable. I've added to the bottom of my question, explaining what's happening.

Comment: maybe StrongParameters prevent that too, overall you're maybe better of having a look into https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters | https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

params convert your id to string while you may be assigning it to an id which is not string which means you should:

```
  @params = params[:charge_id].to_i
```

Share more details and I guess we will be able to solve this issue.

**UPDATE (Debugging help):**

For beginner controller debugging (like you prefer, I guess), before your line where you are getting `@params = params[:charge_id]`:

```
  puts "*"*100
  puts params
  puts "*"*100
```

Now go to console where your server is running and after reloading the page (in browser), Ctrl+Shift+F and enter `*******`. This will find the place where your params are printed. GLHF

Comment: Hi ARK,
I've just put '@params = params[:charge_id].to_i' into my controller, then '<%= @params %>' in my view, and it doesn't return anything :s. I'll keep tinkering

Comment: do you know about gem `byebug`? If not, you need it mate.

Comment: @Oli You should not be checking params in view. you shoudl inspect them at the very point you want to see their value i.e. in controller action because params are meant for controller. Here's the link for you: https://www.fatosmorina.com/debug-ruby-code-using-byebug-gem/

Comment: From what I can see, you are not clear about of role and usage of params. I hope I can help you guide if you are willing to be guided ;)

Comment: Thanks ARK, I'll do some reading up on that. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: ok, before you spend time on that, let me help you for the time being: I am editing my answer for that

Comment: Thanks for the update ARK, I've been able to see the params in the console fine. However, my problem is that I can't seem to access them in the controller in any way. So, I cant run the commented-out lines of code in the activate_charge method.

Comment: That brings us back to importance of byebug :-) Good Luck. It is very simple to use. It will stop the program at that line and u can enter custom code (in server console) for you to see the values at that moment of anything you want. Use `n` for next line and `c` to exit byebug for that time (if in loop).

Comment: Thanks mate. I'll spend some time doing that now.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, anticlimax. 
I noticed that none of the code in the activate_charge method was actually running. I then figured out that having the require_subscription and activate_charge method in the private section of my controller was causing the issue.